# The Iterator's Value WHEN The Loop Stops Executing

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

I was working with this code in Java:

```
int i = 2;
for (int j=0; j < 12; j++) {
    i += j;
}
```

And there was a quiz on the value of `j` *when* the loop stops executing. The value of `j` *after* the loop stops executing is obviously `12`. But, what about *when*?

I was trying to overcome my confusion by adding:

```
System.out.println(j);
```

After the loop statement but it turned out to be an error (could not find a symbol of `j`).

Could anybody please explain? Thank you

Comment: `j` is unknow outside of the loop, since it is defined in the `for` initialization. Put your `System.out.println` inside the loop, and look at its last value .

Comment: When the loop stops executing, it's because `j=12` - so 12 is the `when` value

Answer (score 2):

If you declare `j` inside the loop, `j` has no value after the loop ends, since it gets out of its scope.

If you declare `j` before the loop, you'll be able to print its value after the loop, and it will be 12.

```
int i = 2;
int j = 0;
for (j=0; j < 12; j++) {
    i += j;
}
System.out.println(j);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print out the `j` variable, because it's inlcuded in your for-loop cycle only.

To print it out correctly, you have to define your `j` variable outside the loop.

```
int i=2;
int j;
for (j=0; j<12; j++) {
    i+=j;
}
System.out.println(j);
```

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks. Now I got it :D